# How to add quotes to a string in shell script

Tags: string, shell

I have a string for which i need to add quotes to a substring. How can i do that in shell scripting?

the string is

```
Database.Procedure(Frequency,P1,P2,P3)
```

I have to add single quotes around Frequency.

```
Database.Procedure('Frequency',P1,P2,P3)
```

This should be generic for all such inputs. Please help

Thanks

Comment: You probably want a combination of `sed` (stream editor) and regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this works: `sed "s/Frequency/\'Frequency\'/"`

```
$ echo "Database.Procedure(Frequency,P1,P2,P3)" | sed "s/Frequency/\'Frequency\'/"
Database.Procedure('Frequency',P1,P2,P3)
```

It is a matter of changing the word `Frequency` by the same one with quotes. As the `'` is a reserved word, we have to escape it with `\'`.

---

Your comment:

> But the problem is Frequency can be anything like 'DAILY' , 'WEEKLY' ,
>   'MONTHLY' etc. What should i do for that?

If you want to make it more general, do

```
var="Your_name"
sed "s/$var/\'$var\'/"
```

Examples:

```
$ var=Frequency
$ echo "Database.Procedure(Frequency,P1,P2,P3)" | sed "s/$var/\'$var\'/"
Database.Procedure('Frequency',P1,P2,P3)

$ var=Weekly
$ echo "Database.Procedure(Weekly,P1,P2,P3)" | sed "s/$var/\'$var\'/"
Database.Procedure('Weekly',P1,P2,P3
```

Comment: But the problem is Frequency can be anything like 'DAILY' , 'WEEKLY' , 'MONTHLY' etc. What should i do for that?

Comment: Just updated with more general way of doing it, @user1987193.

Answer (score -1):

try using an escape character

```
Database.Procedure(\'Frequency\',P1,P2,P3)
```

Comment: I think the question is how does one add the quotation marks to an arbitrary string, not how to protect them from shell interpretation.

Comment: exactly. And this is a input parameter and It could be anything. I have to put the quotes based on its position probably?